# Tests with multi-line string are marked as passed when run separately (java+maven+cucumber)

Tags: java, maven, testing, cucumber

I have tests on java + maven + cucumber.
Test creates a request to a remote API (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) and checks that the answer received in json is correct.

Cucumber scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: Check a post body
  When user requests for the post by it's <id> as id
  Then response code is 200
  And response for the post returns correct body <body>

Examples:
|id |body|
|1  |quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto|
|18 |eveniet quo quis\nlaborum totam consequatur non dolor\nut et est repudiandae\nest voluptatem vel debitis et magnam|
... etc...
```

Json responce is parsed by ObjectMapper and stored in java class:

```
package responses;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Posts {

public Posts(){};

private int userId;
private int id;
private String title;
private String body;

public int getUserId() {return userId;}

public void setUserId(int userId) {this.userId = userId;}

public int getId() {return id;}

public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

public String getTitle() {return title;}

public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}

public String getBody() {return body;}

public void setBody (String body) {this.body = body;}}
```

.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Posts post = mapper.readValue(br, Posts.class);
```

And then both strings are compared:

```
@Then("^response for the post returns correct body (.*)")
  public void response_for_the_post_returns_correct_body(String body) throws IOException {
  Assert.assertEquals(body, RequestSender.get_data_from_post("body", connection));
}
```

With the settings like above, when I run a single scenario, it is marked as 'passed' in Idea. But when I run all tests with maven 'mvn test', tests fail.

But if I change 'body string' to something completely different like '12345', it fails when I run single scenario as well.

The problem is only with this 'Body' parameter (I guess, because it contains a multi-string value)

Why does it happen? How I can fix this?

Comment: What are the actual values that are being compared in the assert line? Could be a hint there.

Comment: @Grasshopper

Both are Strings: "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"

Comment: Could you make a test that prints out your default encoding and line endings and compare the results when running via maven and IDEA.

Comment: Ah, I understood where the error was - when I have Cucumber examples with '\n', it reads only the first line of the data. So it actually compared "some text" with "some text\nsome text\nsome text".

Thanks you all for the comments :)